# Can we get the share count of a post in fb using graph api v2.3?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I need to get the shares count of a particular post in fb uisng graph api.
I could'nt find any method to do so. I have followed the link below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/sharedposts

It returns the data of the shared posts in pagination format.
Is there any way to get the total count of the shares without fetching the whole data and without paginating within the data?

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the field `shares` should give you the number of shares for a `POST_ID`

```
[POST_ID]?fields=shares
```

Sample data from my feed

```
{
  "shares": {
    "count": 1
  }, 
  "id": "POST_ID", 
  "created_time": "2015-04-29T09:07:12+0000"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Get shares count :

```
114916098537132_1265715836790480?fields=shares
```

**Bonus [ Get likes + shares + comments ]**

```
114916098537132_1265715836790480?fields=shares,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)
```

**Improved version** *( add limit(0) to removes list of likes and get only summary )*:

```
114916098537132_1265715836790480?fields=shares,likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true)
```